# Multi-condition lookup with dates and text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have been melting my brain trying to work out the formula i need for a multiple conditional lookup.

I have two data sets, one is job data and the other is contract data.
The job data contains customer name, location of job and date of job.  I need to find out if the job was contracted when it took place, and if it was return a value from column N in the contract data.

The problem comes when i try to use the date ranges, as there are frequently more than one contract per customer.

So for example, in my job data:-

CUSTOMER   |    LOCATION     |    JOB DATE

Cust A     |     Port A      |    01/01/2014

Cust A     |     Port B      |    01/02/2014

Customer A had a contract in port B that expired on 21st Feb 2014, so here i would want it to return the value from column N in my contract data as the job was under contract.
Customer A did not have a contract in port A at the time of the job, so i would want it to return 'no contract'.

Contract data has columns containing customer name, port name, and a start and end date value, as well as my lookup category.

I think i need to be using index / match but i can't seem to get them to work with my date ranges.  Is there another type of lookup i can use to get this to work?

Please help, I'm losing the plot!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches here:

1. In both result and source tables make a helper column that concatenates all three values like this: `=A2&B2&C2`. So that you get something like 'Cust APort A01/01/2014'. That is, you get a unique value by which you can identify the row. You can add delimiter if needed: `=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2`. Then you can perform `VLOOKUP` by this value.
2. You can add a helper column with row number (1, 2, 3 ...) in source table. Then you can use `=SUMIFS(<row_number_column>,<source_condition_column_1>,<condition_1>,<source_condition_column_2>,<condition_2>,...)` to return the row number of source table that matches all three conditions. You can use this row number to perform `INDEX` or whatever is needed. But **BE CAREFUL:** check that there are only unique combinations of all three columns in source table, otherwise this approach may return wrong results. I.e. if matching conditions are met in rows `3` and `7` it will return `10` which is completely wrong.

Comment: Well, since OP seems to have difficuties with multi-contition lookup rather that with conditional switching, I think I gave him enough clues.