# How to do Vlookup with multiple criterias, where one of the criterias is max date?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a data range:

```
A    B      C      D  E
m    x   01Feb2014 c 23
n    x   10Apr2014 d 36
n    x   10Feb2014 d 39
r    x   10May2014 e 43
t    z   10Jan2014 d 36
t    y   10Jan2014 d 36
```

Now I want to find the value in column E, where "x" is in Column B, "d" is column D, and has max date in column C,

I try:

```
=INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(1,(($B:$B="x")*($D:$D="d")),0))
```

but I don't know what to do with max date criteria?

Comment: You might have to look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140720/multi-condition-lookup-with-dates-and-text/24141362#24141362

Comment: Something like `{=INDEX($E:$E,MATCH(1,(($B:$B="x")*($D:$D="d")*($C:$C=MAX(($B$2:$B$65000="x")*($D$2:$D$65000="d")*$C$2:$C$65000))),0))}` (entered as an array formula) should work, if column `C` are dates, not text. But I wouldn't do it, because it looks like a maintenance problem down the road.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't do it? Doesn't your formula work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an solution that you can use using an Aggregate function

there are two parts to the soltution.

Part 1) Finding max date of column B = "x" and column D = "d"

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$7/((B2:B7="x")*(D2:D7="d")),1)
```

This will give you the max date.

also this is a great video to watch to get a better understanding of how the formula works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2XCI8Gvz9k

Part 2) Finding the value you can use an `SUMIFS`

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$7,$B$2:$B$7,"x",$D$2:$D$7,"d",$C$2:$C$7,
AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$7/((B2:B7="x")*(D2:D7="d")),1))
```

where the part of the first formula forms your criteria for the max date.

You can adjust the ranges as need be, but that gave the result of max date = 10Apr2014 and value of 36 based on the table above.

Answer (score 0):

`Lookup` can still work if we build a new column F `= concat(B, ":", D, ":", C)`

The value we are searching for `= concat("x:d:", max(C))`

Then we do the `lookup`

```
lookup(concat("x:d:", max(C)), F, E)
```

It's all pseudocode, but the idea is there. Sorry it's untested because I don't have excel installed.